# Por que esta funcion en JavaScript me da indefinido, que debo hacer para que una funcion con varios if me retorne un numero?

Tags: javascript

como hacer para que esta funcion me retorne un numero, por lo regular esta siempre me retorna indefinido, cual puede ser la razon, como puedo retornar correctamente?

```
  Array.prototype.encontraIndex = function(n){ 
    if(Array.prototype.includes(n)){
       for(let i = 0; i < Array.length; i++){
         if(Array[i] === n){
           return  i
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: que es lo que estas buscando hacer ? que contiene tu array ? que es lo que esperas que retorne ? puedes explicar tu código ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que no estás vinculando ([*binding*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding)) correctamente el objeto que representa tu `Array` con la palabra clave [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this). Al contrario, estás intentando usar la clase (Objeto Global) [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) para referirte a la instancia que debe heredar tu [función o método prototipado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Herencia_y_la_cadena_de_protipos).

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, debes reemplazar cada declaración de `Array` (dentro de tu función llamada `encontraIndex()`), por la palabra clave `this`. Además, ya que deseas usar el método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes), puedes hacerlo directamente como un método heredado (todos los objetos del tipo `Array` heredan sus métodos):

```
this.includes(n)
```

o podrías usar el método `apply()` de la siguiente forma:

```
Array.prototype.includes.apply(this, [n])
```

Dado que deseas implementar tu propia función que encuentre el índice de un elemento (ver la función [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf)), lo ideal es que te apegaras un poco a lo que dicha función devuelve. Siendo un valor -1 si el elemento cuyo índice deseas encontrar, no se halla en la lista.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente implementación usa `Array.prototype.includes.apply()` para saber si el elemento buscado existe en la lista:

```js
Array.prototype.encontraIndex = function(n){ 
  if(Array.prototype.includes.apply(this, [n])){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
      if(this[i] === n){
        return  i
      }
    }
  }
  // devolvemos -1 si el valor buscado no está en el Array
  return -1;
}

let miArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

console.log(miArray.encontraIndex("c")); // 2
console.log(miArray.encontraIndex("f")); // -1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver, si el elemento se encuentra en la lista, se devuelve su índice, pero si el mismo no se encuentra, se devuelve `-1`.

Si no deseas usar `apply()` puedes usar directamente `this.includes()`, por ejemplo:

```js
Array.prototype.encontraIndex = function(n){ 
  if(this.includes(n)){
    for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
      if(this[i] === n){
        return  i
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

let miArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

console.log(miArray.encontraIndex("c")); // 2
console.log(miArray.encontraIndex("f")); // -1
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esta es la forma en que se escriben funciones prototipadas en Javascript. Espero que esto aclare tu duda.